# How to list empty folders when `git ls-files --others`?

Tags: git

Based on [git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files/2.1.0#git-ls-files---no-empty-directory):

> --no-empty-directory
> Do not list empty directories. Has no effect without --directory.

Then I think **`git ls-files --others` will list empty folders**.

My system is centos 7.4 with git 1.8.3
Test in a repo as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# git status
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[root@localhost www]mkdir test12345
[root@localhost www]git ls-files --others
[root@localhost www]git status
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

It seemed empty folder `test12345` not list when run `git ls-files --others`.

My questions:
1.How to list empty folders when `git ls-files --others`?
2.What's the usage of `--no-empty-directory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the part **Has no effect without --directory.**

```
git ls-files -o --directory
```

or

```
git ls-files -o --directory --no-empty-directory
```

but not

```
git ls-files -o --no-empty-directory
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one kind of "empty directory" which would still be listed even with  `--no-empty-directory`: nested git repository (gitlink entries, a special  gitdir entry in the index).

Before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "`ls-files -o`" mishandled the top-level directory of another git working tree that hangs in the current working tree.

See [commit ab282aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab282aa548b807c022d521e83d843e4585b89dbb), [commit ed8268d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed8268da107f01efe061151a3fb280f55250b687) (12 Aug 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11f433f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11f433f79c790bcb5feae71b0320161d7ab7dea7), 24 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab282aa548b807c022d521e83d843e4585b89dbb): avoid prematurely marking nonbare repositories as matches
>
> <sup>Reported-by: christian w</sup>
> <sup>Simplified-testcase-and-bisection-by: Kyle Meyer</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Nonbare repositories are special directories.
> Unlike normal directories that we might recurse into to list the files they contain, nonbare repositories must themselves match and then we always report only on the nonbare repository directory itself and not on any of its contents.
>
> Separately, when traversing directories to try to find untracked or excluded files, we often think in terms of paths either matching the specified pathspec, or not matching them.
>
> However, there is a special value that `do_match_pathspec()` uses named `MATCHED_RECURSIVELY_LEADING_PATHSPEC` which means "this directory does not match any pathspec BUT it is possible a file or directory underneath it does."
> That special value prevents us from prematurely thinking that some directory and everything under it is irrelevant, but also allows us to differentiate from "this is a match".
>
> The combination of these two special cases was previously uncovered.
> Add a test to the testsuite to cover it, and make sure that we return a nonbare repository as a non-match if the best match it got was `MATCHED_RECURSIVELY_LEADING_PATHSPEC`.